# Progressbar and label in tablecell

Tags: java, javafx

I need to put in a table cell, one label and progressbar.

For the progressbar, I was using:

```
@FXML
private TableView tableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn columTabela;

@FXML
private TableColumn columSituacao;   

private List<Tabela> lista = new ArrayList<Tabela>();

public List<Tabela> getLista() {
    return lista;
}

public void setLista(List<Tabela> lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
}

   private void test() {

    getLista().add(new Tabela("test", -1.0));
    getLista().add(new Tabela("test1", null));
    columTabela.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Tabela, String>("nome"));
    columSituacao.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Tabela, Double>      ("progresso"));
    columSituacao.setCellFactory(ProgressBarTableCell.forTableColumn()); 
    tableView.getItems().addAll(FXCollections.observableArrayList(lista));
```

But now it is necessary to have one beyond progressbar label inside the cell, could not find a solution to this

Class table:

public class Tabela {

```
private String nome;

private Double progresso;

public Tabela(String nome, Double progresso) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.progresso = progresso;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public Double getProgresso() {
    return progresso;
}

public void setProgresso(Double progresso) {
    this.progresso = progresso;
 }

}
```

While my process is running, you'll have a progressbar in the cell of the table, where the label will change.

I appreciate any help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your own cell factory:

```
Callback<TableColumn<Tabela, Double>, TableCell<Tabela, Double>> cellFactory =
    new Callback<TableColumn<Tabela, Double>, TableCell<Tabela, Double>>() {
public TableCell call(TableColumn<Tabela, Double> p) {
    return new TableCell<Tabela, Double>() {

        private ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
        private Text txt = new Text();
        private HBox hBox = HBoxBuilder.create().children(pb, txt).alignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT).spacing(5).build();
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                pb.setProgress(item);
                txt.setText("value: " + item);
                setGraphic(hBox);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            }
        }
    };
}
};
```

then use it,

```
columSituacao.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
```